# Название полов у собак

Tags: этимология

В общем — собака или пес. Пес-"мужчина" — кобель, собака-"женщина" — сука. Что это за слова, откуда они взялись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все слова, как это часто бывает с наиболее древними бытовыми словами, неясной или спорной этимологии.

Пес - исконно русское; видимо родственно пестрый, пятнистый (в некоторых вариантах также со значением - коричневый, рыжий);
Собака - относительно позднее заимствование, оспаривается иранское или тюркского происхождение;
Сука - индоевропейское, неясно, возможно - c общим значением собака;
Кобель - собственно русское, родства в других языках не имеет, возможно приставочное образование от "ко+бел.." - пестрый, черно-белый.
(по Фасмеру)